# Insert text at cursor in a content editable div

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div where I need to insert text at the caret position,

This can be easily done in IE by  `document.selection.createRange().text = "banana"`

Is there a similar way of implementing this in Firefox/Chrome?

(I know a solution exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621931/insert-text-on-the-current-place-of-the-cursor-in-the-browser/1884285#1884285) , but it can't be used in contenteditable div, and looks clumsy)

Thank you!

Comment: If you wish to insert html at cursor, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-caret-in-a-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 162, accepted):

The following function will insert text at the caret position and delete the existing selection. It works in all the mainstream desktop browsers:

```
function insertTextAtCaret(text) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode( document.createTextNode(text) );
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        document.selection.createRange().text = text;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on comment, here's some code for saving and restoring the selection. Before displaying your context menu, you should store the return value of `saveSelection` in a variable and then pass that variable into `restoreSelection` to restore the selection after hiding the context menu and before inserting text.

```
function saveSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            return sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        return document.selection.createRange();
    }
    return null;
}

function restoreSelection(range) {
    if (range) {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (document.selection && range.select) {
            range.select();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm using this as a part of online code editor in which whenever the user types "." after a object name, a context menu pops-up with a list of its methods (intellisense/ code completion) And when the user clicks a method name, the text needs to be pasted after the dot in the code area div. 

But so far the "method name" gets pasted inside the contextmenu not inside the code area.

Comment: OK. In which case I'd suggest storing a copy of the Range / TextRange representing the selection at the point at which you're about to display the context menu and then restore the selection from that after hiding the context menu but before inserting the text.

Comment: @Tim, is there a built-in Rangy way of doing insertTextAtCursor() instead ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mikel: Not really: you'd just use a cut-down version of the first branch. `function insertTextAtCursor(text) { var range, sel = rangy.getSelection(); if (sel.rangeCount) { range = sel.getRangeAt(0); range.insertNode( document.createTextNode(text) ); } }`

Comment: This works, however (in IE at least, only place I have tested it so far) there is a huge delay (~3 seconds) betweem each insertion. So if I set it up to insert `'text'` when I press a button, I can repetedly click the button but only works every ~3 seconds. If I only use the IE code, it works fine, though it dosn't work with inserting `'\t'` (only makes a space, not a tab).

Comment: @zeel: It shouldn't be that slow. Is there an example page I can see?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zeel/ww3Rk/ tab key inserts `'\t'` and enter key inserts `'\n'`. The insert button inserts `'TEXT'`. Problem present in IE9. Absent in Chrome. Also: how do you make it place the cursor after the insertion? It does this in IE, but in chrome the tab/newline/etc is placed after the cursor, which makes it difficult to use.

Comment: @zeel: I've updated your fiddle to move the cursor to a position immediately after the inserted text: http://jsfiddle.net/ww3Rk/1/. Seems to be fine in IE 9.

Comment: @TimDown, I tried but it is not working with my Editor. More details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881333/wysiwyg-editor-place-html-content-in-current-position

Comment: if select the text out of editor, this method will insert text there. This is not expect

Comment: @Fuxian: I expect it but I'm used to the selection API, which is the same for both editable and non-editable text. If you're worried about that then you could check whether the element containing the selection is editable before inserting the text. I can provide code for that if you need.

Answer (score 23):

1. Get a Selection Object with `window.getSelection()`.
2. Use `Selection.getRangeAt(0).insertNode()` to add a textnode.
3. If necessary, move the cursor position behind the added text with `Selection.modify()`. (Not standardized, but this feature is supported in Firefox, Chrome and Safari)

   ```
   function insertTextAtCursor(text)
   {
       let selection = window.getSelection();
       let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
       range.deleteContents();
       let node = document.createTextNode(text);
       range.insertNode(node);

       for(let position = 0; position != text.length; position++)
       {
           selection.modify("move", "right", "character");
       };
   }
   ```

Comment: This solution has better behaviour than the accepted answer, +1.

Comment: 1+ for the most simple answer to "insert/replace sth. while user is typing".
If I read the doc at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/collapseToEnd correctly, one could use selection.collapseToEnd() without the for() loop.

Comment: @Munneson: have you tried it? That's only if something is currently selected. The inserted node is not selected, it shows up to the right of the selection.

Comment: worked for but only thing is its using a for loop

Comment: Very nice. Worked in Remirror

Comment: after inserting, the inserted text is selected, move ONCE only to deselect: `selection.modify("move", "right", "character");`

Answer (score 11):

UPD: since ~2020 solution is **[obsoleted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand)** (despite it can [work](https://caniuse.com/#search=execCommand) yet)

```
// <div contenteditable id="myeditable">
// const editable = document.getElementById('myeditable')
// editable.focus()
// document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<b>B</b>anana')
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'banana')
```

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand) regarding `execCommand`: This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

Comment: I would really hope that when making `execCommand` obsolete, browsers would have thought of proposing an elegant API to interact with editable content. It didn't happen.

Comment: loved this solution.

Answer (score 4):

I have used next code to insert icons in chat msg

```
<div class="chat-msg-text" id="chat_message_text" contenteditable="true"></div>

<script>
var lastCaretPos = 0;
var parentNode;
var range;
var selection;

$(function(){
    $('#chat_message_text').focus();

    $('#chat_message_text').on('keyup mouseup',function (e){
        selection = window.getSelection();
        range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        parentNode = range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode;
    });
})

function insertTextAtCursor(text) { 

    if($(parentNode).parents().is('#chat_message_text') || $(parentNode).is('#chat_message_text') )
    {
        var span = document.createElement('span');              
        span.innerHTML=text;

        range.deleteContents();        
        range.insertNode(span);  
        //cursor at the last with this
        range.collapse(false);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);

    }
    else
    {
        msg_text = $("#chat_message_text").html()
        $("#chat_message_text").html(text+msg_text).focus()                 
    }
}

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pasting plain text can be handled with the following code.

```
const editorEle = document.getElementById('editor');

// Handle the `paste` event
editorEle.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
    // Prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get the copied text from the clipboard
    const text = e.clipboardData
        ? (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain')
        : // For IE
        window.clipboardData
        ? window.clipboardData.getData('Text')
        : '';

    if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
    } else {
        // Insert text at the current position of caret
        const range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();

        const textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
        range.insertNode(textNode);
        range.selectNodeContents(textNode);
        range.collapse(false);

        const selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with rich editors (like DraftJs) but have no access to their APIs (e.g. modifying from an extension), these are the solutions I've found:

- Dispatching a `beforeinput` event, this is the recommended way, and most editors support

```js
target.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent("beforeinput", {
    inputType: "insertText",
    data: text,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
}))
```

- Dispatching a `paste` event

```js
const data = new DataTransfer();
data.setData(
    'text/plain',
    text
);
target.dispatchEvent(new ClipboardEvent("paste", {
    dataType: "text/plain",
    data: text,
    bubbles: true,
    clipboardData: data,
    cancelable: true
}));
```

This last one uses 2 different methods:

- Using `data` and `dataType` properties. This one works in Firefox
- Using `clipboardData` property. Which works in Chrome but not in Firefox? https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/616#issuecomment-426047799 . Though [It's supposed to work in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/ClipboardEvent), maybe I don't know how to use it or there's a bug.

---

If you want to replace all existing text, you have to select it first

```js
function selectTargetText(target) {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(target);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}

selectTargetText(target)

// wait for selection before dispatching the `beforeinput` event
document.addEventListener("selectionchange",()=>{
    target.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent("beforeinput", {
        inputType: "insertText",
        data: text,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    }))
},{once: true})
```

Comment: Hello, could you share a working example of this approach? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: My answer was specific for rich editors, since they listen to these events. In those examples I gave, you only need to replace `target` and `text`, e.g. `document.getElementById('myId')` and `"sometext"`. `target` must be any Html element inside the rich editor

Answer (score -5):

just an easier method with jquery:

copy the entire content of the div

`var oldhtml=$('#elementID').html();`

`var tobejoined='<span>hii</span>';`

`//element with new html would be`

`$('#elementID').html(oldhtml+tobejoined);`

simple!

Comment: Does not solve the initial question, it appends the text after the content of the html.