# Change dynamically text up to backendresponse

Tags: vue.js

I created vuejs project with npm. This is **App.vue:**

```
<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>
```

This is **helloworld.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="hello">

        <label>File
            <input type="file" id="file" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()"/>
        </label>

        <button v-on:click="submitFile()">Submit</button>



        <span id="error" style="color: red; display: none;">{{message}}</span>
    </div>

</template>
    <script>
        import axios from 'axios';
    
        export default {
            name: 'HelloWorld',
            props: {
                msg: String
            },
            methods: {
      
                submitFile() {
    
                    let formData = new FormData();
    
                    /*
                        Add the form data we need to submit
                    */
                    formData.append('file', this.file); //todo get "file" string from external
    
    
                    /*
                      Make the request to the POST /single-file URL
                    */
                    axios.post('http://localhost:8082/upload/'
                        + this.bank
                        + '/'
                        + this.currency,
                        formData,
                        {
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                            }
                        }
                    ).then(function (response) {
                        console.log('SUCCESS!! + response', response);
                        this.message= "successfully uploaded"
                    })
                        .catch(function (response) {
                            console.log('FAILURE!!+ response', response);
                            this.message= "successfully uploaded"
                        });
                }
            }
        }
    
    </script>
```

It says when it compiles:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "message" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

but i need to show a dynamic messagae according to backend response:

```
 <span id="error" style="color: red; display: none;">{{message}}</span>
```

This is **main.js**:

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Also when i add data under props in helloworld.vue, like this:

```
  export default {
        name: 'HelloWorld',
        props: {
            msg: String
        },
        data: {
            
        },
```

it says:

```
error: `data` property in component must be a function (vue/no-shared-component-data) at src\components\HelloWorld.vue:36:9:
```

I did not change or add any files after npm create. Should i create a new file?

`this.message = "successfully uploaded"` gives `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You have props:

```
props: {
    msg: String
},
```

But you are using `{{message}}` instead.

`data` should be like this (if you need `message` property):

```
data(){
    return {
        message: '',
    };
},
```

Add `created` method like this (if you need to put your `msg` props to `message`):

```
created(){
    this.message = this.msg;
}
```

**Upd.**

Change your code to this (arrow function instead of `function`) (**Upd.2** As mentioned @AJT82 in his answer right before my updates was made):

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: 'HelloWorld',
        props: {
            msg: String
        },
        methods: {

            submitFile() {

                let formData = new FormData();

                /*
                    Add the form data we need to submit
                */
                formData.append('file', this.file); //todo get "file" string from external


                /*
                  Make the request to the POST /single-file URL
                */
                axios.post('http://localhost:8082/upload/'
                    + this.bank
                    + '/'
                    + this.currency,
                    formData,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                        }
                    }
                ).then((response) => {
                    console.log('SUCCESS!! + response', response);
                    this.message= "successfully uploaded"
                })
                    .catch((response) => {
                        console.log('FAILURE!!+ response', response);
                        this.message= "successfully uploaded"
                    });
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Because msg is used in app.vue, in template part. I want to manipulate hellloworld.vue

Comment: ``this.message = "successfully uploaded"`` gives `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined`

Comment: @CanerAydın, I have made an update to my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: @webprogrammer, interesting that you updated your answer after I posted mine, addressing the `this` issue.

Comment: @AJT82, I only answered to new topic starter's question from comments to my answer. You can edit my answer and delete my updates if you need it.

Comment: @AJT82, have you seen my question about your code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849554/how-to-insert-vue-component-into-contenteditable-div ? I mentioned you in my question there.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the upvote tho, but I deleted my answer, makes no sense to have duplicate answers :) +1 to you and have a good weekend!